# How to change MBeanAttributeInfo description field in Java 6?

Tags: attributes, jmx

In my Standard MBean, I'd like to set the Description field that shows up in JConsole under the MBeanAttributeInfo heading. Right now it has a default value of "Attribute exposed for management". I can't seem to figure out how I set that when I define the attribute method in the MBean. I'm using a Java 6 JVM. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Eamonn used to have a really good post about it [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2005/07/adding_informat.html), I am keeping the link as it might help others to find out where it has moved.
It was lost when Oracle moved java.net into their community pages. [This page has similar solution](http://udojava.com/2012/11/13/adding-descriptions-to-jmx-beans-using-an-annotation-wrapper/)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of work, but exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to stackoverflow, and not registered. How do I make this the best answer and/or give you credit for it? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you have the up/down arrows to the left of the answer as a new user but I am glad it helped you anyway. 
It is actually not that much work as soon as you have the proxy class and the annotations in place. I had to do a little work to extend it for NotificationEmitters but it wasn't that hard once you understand how it works.

Comment: Hi Fredrik. I registered, but I don't have enough reputation yet to vote up your answer. I will once I get the reputation. Thanks again.

Comment: Voted down because the blog post is not available anymore... :/

Comment: Wouldn't it be more creative to either mention it so that someone can update the link or do it yourself? Here is a similar post (pretty much the same solution:
http://udojava.com/2012/11/13/adding-descriptions-to-jmx-beans-using-an-annotation-wrapper/